# Save Position of react-draggable objects in react

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-draggable to drag and drop elements. How should I save the elements positions after dragging.

```
<div className={classes.section}>
       <h5>Create Invoice</h5>

      {isEditing ? <Button variant="contained" color="primary">Edit</Button> : <Button variant="contained" color="primary">Update</Button>} </label>
        <div id="target" onDrop={this.drop} onDragOver={this.allowDrop}>
       <Paper className={classes.paper}  >

       <form>

         <Draggable axis="both" bounds="div" disabled={isEditing}>
         <CustomInput select variant="outlined"  label="To" helperText="Please select your company"/></Draggable>
         <Draggable axis="both" bounds="div" disabled={isEditing}><CustomInput name="invoicenumber" label="Invoice Number"/></Draggable>
         <Draggable axis="both" bounds="div" disabled={isEditing}><CustomInput id="Date" label="Issue Date" defaultValue="2019-01-01" type="Date" variant="outlined" InputLabelProps={{shrink:true}}/></Draggable>
         <TextField id="Date" defaultValue="2019-01-01" type="Date" variant="outlined" InputLabelProps={{shrink:true}}/>
         <h5>Item Id</h5> */}
         <Draggable axis="both"  bounds='div' disabled={isEditing}><CustomInput type="textarea" variant="outlined" label="Description"/></Draggable>
         <Draggable axis="both" bounds='Div' disabled={isEditing}>
         <CustomInput type="file" variant="outlined" helperText="Attachments" style={{alignContent:"right"}}/>
         </Draggable>


         </form>

       </Paper>
       </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean on refresh you want the element to be rendered in the same position ?

Comment: yes and on minimization of browser element to be rendered in the same position @Help Please suggest

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: If you still need help I suggest checking this out. Use this persistent state instead of the normal one. https://github.com/leoafarias/use-state-persist

Comment: I found this one: https://codesandbox.io/s/easy-use-drag-inl4h?file=/src/DragTest.js

Answer (score 0):

This is the function for getting the value. Once you get the value then you'll set it a database or localStorage whatever you want.

```
 const eventLogger = (e, data) => {
    localStorage.setItem('defaultPosition', { valueX: data.x, valueY: data.y });
  };
```

This function will be called in Dragable by the event onStop.

```
  <Draggable defaultPosition={{ x: 0, y: 0 }} onStop={eventLogger}>
    <h2 style={{ cursor: 'grab' }}>
      dragable
    </h2>
  </Draggable>
```